# The function disable inputs is not working for wrong answers idk why its happening I tried all the things

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable all inputs other than the user clicked once the user clicks on any of the radio button. Its working fine when I'm clicking a right answer. But not working with wrong answers.
And please tell me how can I improve my code to make it more production grade.

I tried console log on everything I can but nothing worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./quiz.css" />
    <script defer src="./quiz.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="question-container">
        <div class="start-menu" >
            <h2>Play the quiz to know how much you aware about air pollution</h2>
            <button>Start</button>
        </div>
        <div class="question-box" style="display: none; opacity: 0;">
          <div class="question">
            <span id="q_num"></span>
            <span id="question">
              
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="answers">
            <div class="answers-group">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" value="" />
              <label for="option1"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="answers-group">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" value="" />
              <label for="option2"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="answers-group">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" value="" />
              <label for="option3"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="answers-group">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" value="" />
              <label for="option4"></label>
            </div>
            <p class="result"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="toggles">`your text`
            <button class="finish">Finish</butt

on>
            <button class="next">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="result-box" style="display: none; opacity: 0;">
            <h2 class="greeting">Congratulations</h2>
            <div>
                <h3>Here are your results...</h3>
                <p class="percentage"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
---js---
const DATA = [
  {
    question: "What do you mean by AQI?",
    answers: [
      "Air Quantity Inclusion",
      "Air Quality Index",
      "Air Quotient Index",
      "None of these",
    ],
    correctAnswer: "Air Quality Index",
  },
  {
    question: "What is considered the good air quality range on AQI?",
    answers: ["100 - 200", " 300 - 400", "50 - 100", "None of these"],
    correctAnswer: "50 - 100",
  },
  {
    question: " Which color on the AQI Metre depicts the good quality of air?",
    answers: ["Yellow", "Green", "Red", "Violet"],
    correctAnswer: "Green",
  },
  {
    question:
      " Which of the following statements is true about the Air Quality Index?",
    answers: [
      "Indicates the color of the air",
      "Predicts ozone levels in your area",
      "Determines the intensity of sound and sound pollution",
      "Estimates air pollution, mainly sulphur content in the air",
    ],
    correctAnswer: "Estimates air pollution, mainly sulphur content in the air",
  },
  {
    question: "Which of these is the major source of air pollution in a city?",
    answers: [
      "Vehicular emissions",
      "Construction",
      "Stubble burning",
      "All of these",
    ],
    correctAnswer: "All of these",
  },
  {
    question: "Which of the stakeholders from the following can increase AQI?",
    answers: ["Politician", "Common person", "Industrialist", "All of them"],
    correctAnswer: "All of them",
  },
  {
    question: " Which stakeholder can influence a city's air quality policies?",
    answers: ["Farmers", "Builders", "Politicians", "All of them"],
    correctAnswer: "All of them",
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which industries play a major role in polluting air and increasing air pollution?",
    answers: [
      "Brick manufacturing industries",
      "Manufacture of gases industries",
      "Electrical appliances and electrical goods industries",
      "All of them",
    ],
    correctAnswer: "All of them",
  },
  {
    question:
      "What actions would you undertake as an Industrialist to decrease the AQI?",
    answers: [
      "Burn coal",
      "Make new environmental policies",
      "Make eco-friendly industries",
      "Use Plastic",
    ],
    correctAnswer: "Make eco-friendly industries",
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which issues are caused by the increased levels of Air pollution?",
    answers: [
      "Soil Erosion",
      "Respiratory problems",
      "Obesity",
      "All of these",
    ],
    correctAnswer: "All of these",
  },
  {
    question: "Which one of them is the most affected by bad air quality?",
    answers: ["Pregnant Women", "Children", "Young Adults", "All of these"],
    correctAnswer: "All of these",
  },
  {
    question: "Which one of the following is the most polluted state in India?",
    answers: ["Bangalore", "Kolkata", "Delhi", "Mumbai"],
    correctAnswer: "Delhi",
  },
];

const question = document.querySelector("#question");
const quesNum = document.querySelector("#q_num");
const answerLabel = document.querySelectorAll(".answers .answers-group label");
const answerInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".answers .answers-group input");

const nextbtn = document.querySelector(".toggles .next");
const finishBtn = document.querySelector(".toggles .finish");
const startBtn = document.querySelector(".start-menu button");
const result = document.querySelector(".result");
const startMenu = document.querySelector(".start-menu");
const questionBox = document.querySelector(".question-box");
const resultBox = document.querySelector('.result-box');
const percentage = document.querySelector('.percentage');

let counter = 1;
let score_count = 0;

// console.log(DATA.length);
// console.log(counter);

function showQuestions(id) {
  const data = DATA[counter - 1];
  quesNum.innerHTML = `Q${counter}. `;
  question.innerHTML = data["question"];

  answerLabel.forEach((label, index) => {
    label.innerHTML = data["answers"][index];
    answerInputs[index].value = data["answers"][index];
  });
}

function disableInputs(index) {
  index
    ? answerInputs.forEach((input, i) => {
        if (i !== index) input.disabled = true;
      })
    : answerInputs.forEach((input) => (input.disabled = false));
}

function reset() {
  answerInputs.forEach((input) => (input.checked = false));
  result.innerHTML = "";
  result.classList.remove("green", "red");
}

function checkAnswer(value, index, correctOption) {
  const answerData = DATA.filter((obj) => obj.question === correctOption);
    // console.log(answerData.length);
  const answer = answerData[0].correctAnswer;
  const answerValue = DATA.filter(quesObj => quesObj.question === correctOption).reduce((acc, obj) => acc = obj.correctAnswer, "");
  // console.log(answerValue);
  if (answerValue !== value) 
  {
    // console.log('correct')
    disableInputs(index);
    result.innerHTML = `Wrong - correct answer was ${answer}`;
    result.classList.add("red");
    
  } else {
    score_count++;
    result.innerHTML = "Correct Answer";
    result.classList.add("green");
    disableInputs(index);
  }
  
}

answerInputs.forEach((input, index) => {
  input.addEventListener("change", () =>
    checkAnswer(input.value, index, question.innerHTML)
  );
});

// Added listener on start button to start the quiz
startBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  startMenu.style.opacity = "0";
  startMenu.style.display = "none";
  questionBox.style.display = "flex";
  setTimeout(() => {
    questionBox.style.opacity = "1";
    showQuestions(counter);
  }, 600);
});

finishBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    questionBox.style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(() => {
      questionBox.style.display = "none";
    showQuestions(counter);
  }, 600);

  resultBox.style.display = "flex";
  setTimeout(() => {
    resultBox.style.opacity = "1";
  }, 700);
  
  percentage.innerHTML = `you scored ${Math.round((score_count / DATA.length) * 100)}%`;

})

nextbtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (counter < DATA.length) counter++;
  showQuestions(counter);
  disableInputs();
  reset();
  // console.log(counter);

  if (counter === DATA.length) {
    nextbtn.style.display = "none";
    return;
  }
});
```

Comment: No idea what the problem is supposed to be - I put your code into https://jsfiddle.net/fu9evp0r/, and even in a case where it tells me "Wrong - correct answer was XY" after clicking a radio button, all the other ones are clearly getting set to disabled. (Tested in a Chromium-based browser.)

Comment: _"And please tell me how can I improve my code to make it more production grade."_ - by keeping on learning, and improving over time. (This here is not a place for code review, or to get "better" techniques taught in a tutorial-style fashion.)